# How to get count of Employee activity by Manager in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataset that uses numpy and pandas and looks at employees by ID # and all activity like promotion, termination, job switch, and etc. What I want to do is know how to count the number of changes and group them to the manager.

Here is a sample of the data. For Reference: 1 = Yes 0 = No

```
ID     Date       Job_Title        ManagerID   Status  Terminated  Job_Change  Team_Change
 1   May 2022     Sales Rep            7       Active      0            0           0
 1   Oct 2022     Sales Consultant     7       Active      0            1           0
 1   Jan 2023     Sales Consultant     7       Active      0            0           0
 2   Feb 2022     Tech Advisor         3       Active      0            0           0
 2   May 2022     Tech Advisor         3       Termed      1            0           0
 3   Dec 2021     Sales Supervisor     7       Active      0            0           0
 3   Jan 2022     Tech Supervisor      10      Active      0            1           1
 3   Feb 2023     Tech Manager         10      Active      0            1           0
```

What I want the output to look like:

```
ManagerID    Terminated    Job_Change  Team Change
    3            1             0            0
    7            0             1            0
    10           0             2            1
```

Is their a way to print this output out without having to create a new dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried something like `df.groupby('ManagerID').sum()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired output by using the Pandas library to group your dataset by the ManagerID and then aggregating the number of events in each category (Terminated, Job_Change, Team_Change).

Here's a Python script using the Pandas library to do this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Assuming your data is stored in a DataFrame called 'data'

# Group the data by 'ManagerID' and sum the respective columns
result = data.groupby('ManagerID')[['Terminated', 'Job_Change', 
'Team_Change']].sum()

# Reset the index to make 'ManagerID' a column again
result = result.reset_index()

print(result)
```

This script groups your data by the ManagerID and then calculates the sum of the Terminated, Job_Change, and Team_Change columns. The output will be a new DataFrame with the desired format.